# GameObject reflecting off another gameObject error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new at Unity/c# and I wanted to make a pong game. I made this by watching a tutorial on youtube. There is no "error" except the ball doesn't move after touching the player.

This is ball code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            
            
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        position.x = position.x - 5.8f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

This is ball bounce code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallBounce : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector3 lastVelocity;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lastVelocity = rb.velocity;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        var speed = lastVelocity.magnitude;
        var direction = Vector3.Reflect(lastVelocity.normalized, coll.contacts[0].normal);

        
    }

}
```

And this is player code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 4.5f;





    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        

        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        position.y = position.y + moveSpeed * vertical * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }

   
}
```

When I play the game the ball will collide with player, but it won't ricochet.

Comment: Your ball only moves one direction the bounce code becomes irrelevant. Each frame you push it the same way. Why not just let physics do all the work

Answer (score 2):

Your OnCollisionEnter2D method is not doing anything except set local variables that are quickly discarded. You need to make speed and direction variables of the BallCode or BallBounce class, then set up the BallCode class to use those variables in Update() when determining the motions it makes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a 2D rigid body property to the sphere and removing gravity.

[image]

Add a C# script to control the movement of the ball and add a 2D collider to the ball.

```
//Initial velocity
 public float speed = 100f;

 void Start()
 {
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce
     (Vector2.right * speed);
  
 }
```

Add a 2D collider:

[image]

Add a 2D physical material to the sphere, so that the ball can bounce.

[image]

Modify 2D Physical Material Properties.

Added to the sphere's material.

[image]

Add player (Square) and control player movement script.

```
void Update()
{
   // The mouse moves with the player
    float y = Camer.main.ScreenToWorldPoint
    (Input.mousePosition).y
    this.transform.position = new Vector3
    (transform.position.x,y,0);
}
```

Add the wall around the screen and the script Wall to control the randomness of the vertical speed and the direction of the ball when the ball collides with the wall.

```
 public class Wall : MonoBehaviour
{
   //Initial velocity
   public float speed = 100f;

   // Triggered when the collision ends
   private void OnCollisionExit(Collision2D collision)
  {
     
     int r = 1;
     if(Random.Range(0, 2) != -1)
     {
         r *= -1;
     }

     //add a vertical force
     collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().
     AddForce(Vector2.up.*speed*r);

   }
}
```

achieve effect:

[image]